# Laravel error when installing Pagseguro, Doctrine and JMS

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

I am getting this error when I'm trying to make payment request. I install JMS and doctrine but I think that its not working correctly?

```
AnnotationException in AnnotationException.php line 54:
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@JMS\Serializer\Annotation\AccessType" in 
class PHPSC\PagSeguro\Requests\Checkout\Checkout does not exist, or could not 
be auto-loaded.
```

Comment: do you have this class in your project? src or vendor?

Comment: I install it via composer and it located in the vendor folder, but I dont know what to write in controller.

Comment: Did you add the provider and the alias to your `config/app.php` file?

Comment: No, I did not find in documantation what should I add.